# Find the Taylor series of a function of two variables, check my answer.

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I want to find Taylor expantion of the function with two variables $f(x_i+p_1h,y_i+q_1k_1h)$ .

If $y'_i=f(x_i,y_i)=f_i$, 
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x_i+p_1h,y_i+q_1k_1h)&=&f(x_i,y_i)+p_1hf_x+q_1k_1hf_y\nonumber\\
&=&f_i+p_1hf_x+q_1k_1hf_y
\end{eqnarray}

Please check my answer. Is it  correct or incorrect?